# How to debug offscreen page in chrome extension manifest v3?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, browser-extension

I'd like to use chrome extension mv3 offscreen page to do clipboard, and it works.
But when I add some logs in offscreen.js like

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(handleMessages);

console.log('clipboard')
```

I could not see the logs in console
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xadfi.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQl9D.png)

So is there anyway to debug in offscreen page?

Comment: It's almost like debugging a service worker.

Comment: Judging by your screenshot you need to uncheck "Selected context only" or select the proper context in the console toolbar.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this is to go to the `chrome://inspect/#other` debug page and find your offscreen page there. But if the offsceen window closes too quickly or for some other reason you can't use this method, then I can suggest another way. You can create a helper function to send logs to background script:

```js
const log = async (...args: any[]) => chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
  target: 'background',
  type: 'log',
  data: args,
});
```

And in the background script add listener:

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message) => {
  if (message.target !== 'background') {
    return;
  }
  if (message.type === 'log') {
    console.log(message.data);
  }
});
```

And now from offscreen page you can just call the `log` function:

```js
log('clipboard');
```

Answer (score 0):

you can see `console.log` message of offscreen page.

1. go to `chrome://extensions`.
2. find your extension and go detail.
3. go to `Inspect Views` sections and click your offscreen page.

then you can see log by chrome devTool console.

see Simeon Vincent's answer here : https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/chromium-extensions/c/MTNK0hGdyuM